# Grails integrations tests run on Jenkins

Tags: grails, jenkins, integration-testing

I was trying to deploy a Grails app(ver. 2.2.2) to Jenkins(ver. 1.638). It runs `clean`, `test-app -Dgrails.env=XXX` and `war` commands.

The `clean` and `war` worked great. For the `test-app -Dgrails.env=XXX`, the unit test part worked fine, every test case passed. However, most integration test cases failed. It seems that domain classes in the controller cannot get data. In the other words, the `get()` or `list()` methods didn't return correct records. I'm assuming the database is connected correctly because console output didn't complain the connection issue. The integration tests runs well on my local machine with the same datasource.

Test errors look like the following code, the `size()` is always 0. It is a controller integration test. The `results` is returned by `get()`, `list()` or `createCriteria().list{}` methods of domain classes in the controller.

```
results.size() == 9
|       |      |
[]      0      false
```

The following is the code in the DataSource.groovy. I have tried both `testCI` and `testCI2`. Both settings don't help. Honestly, I don't know much about the `pool properties`. I just copied it.

```
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = false
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}

environments {
testCI {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/build_db" // For non network testing
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username ="build"
        password = "build"
        pooled=true
        properties {
            maxActive = -1
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=true
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}

testCI2 {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/build_db" // For non network testing
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username ="build"
        password = "build"
    }
}
}
```

**The most weirdest part is that the integration test sometimes works well after I push new commits to the git repository. It's not really often though.**

Does anyone have any ideas about it? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Can you share your  `DataSource.groovy` with us? Just to see if your test database is configured correctly (normally integration tests launch in memory `h2` and test against it)

Comment: Thanks @defectus. I just shared the DataSource.groovy. I use `mysql` database instead of the `h2`. I will try h2 if I have to.

Comment: Unless jenkins is installed on your local computer, you are not using the same database because you use localhost as hostname. So verify if you have required data in your server database and if entries you query exists there

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @droggo. I do need the change hostname!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, unit tests run on a memory-based GORM representation.

For integration tests, you'll need a real (from your example, MySQL) database.

Is MySQL installed on the Jenkins server -- that's the localhost when your integration tests are being run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The MySQL database is installed on a host in the same LAN of Jenkins server. I created a tunnel so that I am able to connect to the MySQL database using `localhost` on my local machine. Anyway, your answer reminds me that the MySQL database is not on the Jenkins server. The problem is solved when I change the `localhost` to the ip address.